# BreezeController Controller Issue

Tags: entity-framework, lazy-loading, breeze

I have a simple BreezeController that returns a unit of work repository object. The object is a DbSet entity object of the class below:

```
    public int OrderId { get; set; }
    public string Customer { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<OrderLine> OrderLines { get; set; }
```

The Unit of Work class is as follows:

```
private readonly EFContextProvider<ESpaDBEntities> _contextProvider;

    public UoW()
    {
        _contextProvider = new EFContextProvider<ESpaDBEntities>();
        Orders = new Repository<Order>(_contextProvider.Context);
        OrderLine = new Repository<OrderLine>(_contextProvider.Context);
        Products = new Repository<Product>(_contextProvider.Context);

    }

    public IRepository<Order> Orders { get; set; }
    public IRepository<OrderLine> OrderLine { get; set; }
    public IRepository<Product> Products { get; set; }

    public SaveResult Commit(JObject changeSet)
    {
        return _contextProvider.SaveChanges(changeSet);
    }
```

The BreezeController action is as follows:

```
[HttpGet]
    public IQueryable<Order> Orders()
    {
        return uow.Orders.All();
    }
```

When I access this method from my browser the following Json object is returned:

```
$id: "1",$type: "KoDurandalBreeze.DomainModel.Order, KoDurandalBreeze",OrderId: 1,Customer: "Bob",OrderLines: [ ]
```

For whatever reason, orderlines are not populated even though virtual is specified. Does anyone have any ideas of why the JSON object would not contain any OrderLine objects?

Answer (score 0):

You will need to either perform the equivalent of an EF 'Include' on the server or if this is an EF Queryable you can call 'extend' on your client side EntityQuery, i.e.

```
  var query = EntityQuery.from("Orders").expand("OrderDetails");
  var myEntityManager.executeQuery(query).then(...)
```